# glide image loading timeout increase

Tags: android, timeout, android-glide

I am using glide to load images from URL. 
While I am fetching the images I am showing a loader in the image view.
Some of the images being fetched are larger and therefore in slow internet connection timeout occurs and throws exception

How can I increase the timeout?

Comment: Did you try using OK HTTP instead of volley? Like explained here: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Integration-Libraries#okhttp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After searching a lot finally got an answer, if you are using volley:

```
public class CustomGlide implements GlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue( // params hardcoded from Volley.newRequestQueue()
                new DiskBasedCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "volley")),
                new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack())) {
            @Override public <T> Request<T> add(Request<T> request) {
                request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 1, 1));
                return super.add(request);
            }
        };
        queue.start();
        glide.register(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new VolleyUrlLoader.Factory(queue));
    }
}
```

Change the `DefaultRetryPolicy` according to your need

And in the manifest:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="<package-name>.CustomGlide"
            android:value="GlideModule" />
```

Comment: I have declared customGlide class as you say but now how to use it in glide load image line in java class ?

Comment: Now the glide is configured with the timeout you provided.
Just request the image using
Glide.with(context).load(url).into(ImageView)

Comment: For VolleyUrlLoader you need to add:                                                 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:volley-integration:1.5.0@aar' to your dependencies.

Comment: To avoid [conflict](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#conflicting-glidemodules) with `VolleyGlideModule` that is added automatically to merged manifest if you use Gradle, you must manually exclude it by adding another metadata entry: `<meta-data android:name="com.bumptech.glide.integration.volley.VolleyGlideModule"
                   tools:node="remove" />`

Comment: @knezmilos it shows me unresolved supertype error at compilation on VolleyUrlLoader

Answer (score 16):

You can use this method of the new version of glide

```
.timeout(60000)
```

the final code sample will be:

```
Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
        .load(finalUrl)
        .timeout(60000)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
        .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 11):

Below is the solution for: `Glide 4.3.1` & `OkHttp 3.9.1`, a bit different than before (it's no more `OkHttpGlideModule` but `AppGlideModule`).

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.3.1'
```

**CustomGlideModule**

```
@GlideModule
public class CustomGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.readTimeout(YOUR_CUSTOM_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.writeTimeout(YOUR_CUSTOM_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.connectTimeout(YOUR_CUSTOM_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        registry.append(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(builder.build()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you would like to use `OkHttp`, please import `glide:okhttp-integration` according to [this](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Integration-Libraries#okhttp), and then implement your own `OkHttpGlideModule`:

```
@GlideModule
public class CustomGlideModule extends OkHttpGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        // stub
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
        final OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        // set your timeout here
        builder.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        glide.register(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(builder.build()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
.timeout(30000)
```

Shortest way to do that:

```
Glide.with(this)
         .setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions()
         .timeout(30000))
         .load("https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58063088/edit")
         .placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_image))
         .error(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.no_image))                
         .into(imageView);
```