# How to add timeout to glide in library module without using @GlideModule

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-glide

I'm using Glide in my library and trying to increase the timeout

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339402/glide-image-loading-timeout-increase) but using `AppGlideModule` in the library [is discouraged](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#avoid-appglidemodule-in-libraries)

and [`LibraryGlideModule`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/configuration.html#libraries) doesn't generate any api and is not intended to be consumed by the library itself.

I want a way to set the timeout without using the generated api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RequestOptions.timeoutOf(5000)` which will change the timeout from the default **2500ms**

it's also an easy way if you don't want to use the generated api just for the timeout.

full example:

```
Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .apply(RequestOptions.timeoutOf(5 * 60 * 1000))
            .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method of glide

```
.timeout(60000)
```

the final code sample will be:

```
Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
            .load(finalUrl)
            .timeout(60000)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.place_holder)
            .into(imageView);
```