# Using Glide to download images from Firebase - how to implement a timeout?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am successfully using Glide to download images from Firebase.

I have my standard GlideModule:

```
@GlideModule
public class MyGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

And then this in my Activity:

```
GlideApp.with(this /* context */)
        .load(storageReference)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .fitCenter()
        .error(R.drawable.broken)
        .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade(2000))
        .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                Log.i("Info","Load failed");
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                Log.i("Info","Load successful");
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(imageView);
```

This works fine usually, but when the device has no internet connection the imageview remains blank - the `R.drawable.broken` error image isn't triggered and neither `onLoadFailed` or `onResourceReady` are triggered. If the signal is restored then the image turns up.

I would like to detect that this is happening and flag to the user that they need better signal. It seems the obvious way is by implementing a timeout (as there doesn't seem to be one). However simply adding `.timeout(3000)` to the Activity section doesn't work as this is ignored when using a GlideModule. I am assuming the answer lies somewhere within the setup of `FirebaseImageLoader.Factory()` but I can't find any documentation and it's not clear from the source code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339402/glide-image-loading-timeout-increase

Comment: Thanks, I saw this but it doesn't apply here as they are not using a FirebaseImageLoader. Their Factory object takes a queue parameter, in which they have encoded a timeout, whilst the FirebaseImageLoader.Factory takes no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I came here since I encountered with the same requirements, so I am happy to share my thought after my research.

`FirebaseImageLoader` doesn't support timeout option when setting thru `Glide`'s builder. You will needs to either creating your own custom loader or workaround by make use of existing timeout value.

It should be noted that timeout that can be set to Glide by default is intended to be used for network timeout.

`Glide`'s timeout is stored in an option keyed `HttpGlideUrlLoader.TIMEOUT` where you can retrieves it via `RequestBuilder.getOptions().get(HttpGlideUrlLoader.TIMEOUT)`.

My suggestion for workaround if you are using Coroutines is as follows:

```
suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    addListener(
        object : RequestListener<T> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(
                ex: GlideException?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<T>?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                continuation.resumeWithException(ex ?: RuntimeException())
                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: T,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<T>?,
                dataSource: DataSource?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                continuation.resume(resource)
                return false
            }
        }
    ).submit().get(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
}
```

In case of custom loader, you can use existing `FirebaseImageLoader` source as a base and doing some modification. The loader knows about Glide's options so you can get timeout from it and pass to fetch where it is responsible for getting data from Firebase Storage and do your own custom handling, e.g.

FirebaseImageLoader

```
// ...
    ): ModelLoader.LoadData<InputStream> {
        val timeout = options.get(HttpGlideUrlLoader.TIMEOUT) ?: 2_500
        return ModelLoader.LoadData(
            FirebaseStorageKey(ref),
            FirebaseStorageFetcher(ref, timeout)
        )
    }
// ...
```

FirebaseStorageFetcher

```
// ...
    override fun loadData(priority: Priority, callback: DataFetcher.DataCallback<in InputStream>) {
        try {
            stream = Tasks
                .await(ref.stream.also { this.task = it }, timeout.toLong(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .stream
            callback.onDataReady(stream)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            callback.onLoadFailed(ex)
        }
    }
// ...
```

Lastly, register your own classes to your `GlideModule`.